# TypeError: Cannot read property ' ' error with discord.js

Tags: node.js, database, discord.js, typeerror, fs

So I have figured out how to set up a simple database with discord.js in a users.json file and my !start cmnd works to create the users database, but when me and my cousin tried the !daily cmnds, the cmnd seems to be fine but I get this error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'a number' of undefined. I believe the number refers to my user number or database number (a number means an actual long number, not "a number").

Also here is the code that goes along with this that is in my index.js file:

```
var UserJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync('./DB/users.json'));
            UserJSON[message.author.id] = {
                bal: 0,
                lastclaim: 0,
            }
            Fs.writeFileSync('./DB/users.json', JSON.stringify(UserJSON));

            let SuccessEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            SuccessEmbed.setTitle("**SUCCESS**");
            SuccessEmbed.setDescription("You have joined the economy! type !help to get started");
            message.channel.send(SuccessEmbed);
            return;
        }
        if (args[0] == "daily") {
            let userJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync('./DB/users.json'));
            if (Math.floor(new Date().getTime() - UserJSON[message.author.id].lastclaim) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) < 1) {
                let WarningEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                WarningEmbed.setTitle("**ERROR**");
                WarningEmbed.setDescription("You have claimed today already");
                message.channel.send(WarningEmbed);
                return;
            }
            UserJSON[message.author.id].bal += 500;
            UserJSON[message.author.id].lastclaim = new Date().getTime();
            Fs.writeFileSync('./DB/users.json', JSON.stringify(UserJSON));
            let SuccessEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            SuccessEmbed.setTitle("**SUCCESS**");
            SuccessEmbed.setDescription("You have claimed a daily reward of 500 coins!");
            message.channel.send(SuccessEmbed);
        }
    }
})
```

Also to specify, the ./DB/users.json refers to the folder DB for database and users.json is the file that stores the databases.

Here is what the user.json file looks like:

```
{"*my database number*":{"bal":0,"lastclaim":0},"*my cousin's database number*":{"bal":0,"lastclaim":0}}
```

Is there any code I need to add into my index.js file to stop this from happening. If possible, answer as soon as possible so I can get this error worked out. Thank You!

Edit: I somehow figured this out by re-doing it and this is the finished product if anyone wants to start an economy bot:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Fs = require("fs");

const prefix = "!";

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ready!");
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        
        var args = message.content.substr(prefix.length)
            .toLowerCase()
            .split(" ");
        if (args[0] == "start") {

            let UserJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync("./DB/users.json"));
            UserJSON[message.author.id] = {
                bal: 0,
                lastclaim: 0,
            }
            Fs.writeFileSync("./DB/users.json", JSON.stringify(UserJSON));

            let SuccessEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            SuccessEmbed.setTitle("**SUCCESS**");
            SuccessEmbed.setDescription("You have joined the economy! type !help to get started");
            message.channel.send(SuccessEmbed);
            return;
        }
        if (args[0] == "daily") {
            let UserJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync("./DB/users.json"));
            if (Math.floor(new Date().getTime() - UserJSON[message.author.id].lastclaim) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) < 1) {
                let WarningEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                WarningEmbed.setTitle("**ERROR**");
                WarningEmbed.setDescription("You have claimed today already");
                message.channel.send(WarningEmbed);
                return;
            }
            UserJSON[message.author.id].bal += 500;
            UserJSON[message.author.id].lastclaim = new Date().getTime();
            Fs.writeFileSync("./DB/users.json", JSON.stringify(UserJSON));
            let SuccessEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
            SuccessEmbed.setTitle("**SUCCESS**");
            SuccessEmbed.setDescription("You have claimed a daily reward of 500 discord coins!");
            message.channel.send(SuccessEmbed);
        }
    }
})
client.login('your token');
```

also remember to make a DB folder with an users.json file

Comment: This question can't be answered without seeing your code. Please provide more details in your question, including adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others better answer your question.

Comment: I have added my code, which I already found to be the minimal reproducible example, for there's really no way to shorten or modify this because it is very basic code. If you need anything else, just ask because I would really like to be able to fix my problem.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: That is what I'm confused about. The error happens when I use the daily command, but I dont think that its the specific command since it's saying it cant read the properties of the user database number, which leads me to believe it may be in the first line of code that I have on here.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? There should be an associated line number. What's the line number, and which line in your question does it correspond to?

Comment: So the error corresponds to the database in my users.json file in my DB folder, and so far the only people data that I have in the database our mine and my cousin's because I haven't had anyone else try out the bot since it's not finished. I added the code in the users.json file into my question since you can't really add code in comments. That is in the #1 line because that's the only thing that's stored in that file.

Comment: What was added was the stuff that cannot have it's properties read by the bot. The other code that I believe may be the issue and need to be fixed would be #1-5 lines on this code or my #19-23 on my vscode. See the thing is I'm not sure if that is the code that is causing the issue, for I thought you would be able to find that issue based on any code that you needed provided, and that you would be able to tell me how to fix it.

Comment: So I went back and re-did everything and now it works. Tbh I don't know what I did. I think I left a line of code out. I'll put the correct code up there for anyone who needs it, and ty for your help.

Comment: If you figure out your issue, instead of editing the question you can answer your own and accept it. That way if anyone else runs into your problem and comes across this question they'll be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem with the code is that instead of vars, it needed to be let before the UserJSON, so the line of code should read:

```
 let UserJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync("./DB/users.json"));
            UserJSON[message.author.id] = {
                bal: 0,
                lastclaim: 0,
            }
```